# find the digit and replace it

Tags: python, regex

i have a string like that:

```
This changes are related to book:id:pages:3000 location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip
This changes are related to book:id:pages:30ab00e location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip
```

In this i want to replace the digit or numbers(and some times numbers are hexadecimal also) with "my_doc"
I tried with:

```
 match = re.findall("[\.0-9]*",text)
print match
```

But it working only for numbers or digit, it should also work for hexadecimal numbers and replace the number with "my_doc" and print the whole line
output:

```
This changes are related to book:id:pages:my_doc location /file1/file2/file3/pages.my_doc.zip
This changes are related to book:id:pages:my_doc location /file1/file2/file3/pages.my_doc.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
In [8]: import re


In [14]: strs="This changes are related to book:id:pages:3000 location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

In [15]: re.findall(r"\d+[A-Ea-e]{0,}\d+[A-Ea-e]{0,}",strs)

Out[15]: ['3000', '000']

In [16]: strs1="This changes are related to book:id:pages:30ab00e location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

In [17]: re.findall(r"\d+[A-Ea-e]{0,}\d+[A-Ea-e]{0,}",strs1)

Out[17]: ['30ab00e', '000']
```

use `re.sub()` for  replacing :

```
In [68]: strs="This changes are related to book:id:pages:3000 location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

In [69]: re.sub(r"(\d+[A-Ea-e]*\d+[A-Ea-e]*)|(\d+)","my_doc",strs)

Out[69]: 'This changes are related to book:id:pages:my_doc location /filemy_doc/filemy_doc/filemy_doc/pages.my_doc.zip'

In [70]: strs1="This changes are related to book:id:pages:30ab00e location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

In [71]: re.sub(r"(\d+[A-Ea-e]*\d+[A-Ea-e]*)|(\d+)","my_doc",strs1)
Out[71]: 'This changes are related to book:id:pages:my_doc location /filemy_doc/filemy_doc/filemy_doc/pages.my_doc.zip'

In [72]: foo=" number of pages completed, 2 still pending" 

In [73]: re.sub(r"(\d+[A-Ea-e]*\d+[A-Ea-e]*)|(\d+)","my_doc",foo)
Out[73]: ' number of pages completed, my_doc still pending'
```

Comment: But the same regular expression will not valid on this: number of pages completed, 2 still pending  I want to make a common which will work on all the numbers and hexa decimal also....And how can i replace it and get the output as mentioned above

Comment: @SuryaGupta  you can use `re.sub()` here to get the expected output, and worked on both the examples you mentioned.

Comment: I agreed... But i want a common regex which will work on all the string which contain the digit and hexa numbers but unfortunately it is not working on this string " number of pages completed, 2 still pending"

Comment: @SuryaGupta glad that helped, you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it worked for you by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: if we try the same on this string "Books: pages [0-9]6 : not completed" then output is not proper like "Books: pages my_doc : not completed"

Comment: @SuryaGupta No, I get this : `'Books: pages [my_doc-my_doc]my_doc : not completed'`. See http://ideone.com/oQpjuN.

Comment: output should be like this "Books: pages my_doc : not completed"

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional in your regex: http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regex/regex-conditionals.html

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy (So as your question) and hackish!

Hex characters (a-z, A-Z) appear at many places in the string, so those would get replaced which (thought the question doesn't object atm ;) ) doesn't seem expected behavior.

Assuming that the blob/portion to be removed is the hex word, and assuming it's min length is 3, consider:

```
import re
from string import hexdigits


str_1 = "This changes are related to book:id:pages:3000 location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

str_2 = "This changes are related to book:id:pages:30ab00e location /file1/file2/file3/pages.000.zip"

expression = '[%s]{3,}'%(string.hexdigits)  # = '[' + hexdigits + ']{3,}'
re.sub(exp, 'my_doc', str_1)
```

*Edit:* Ok a little less crazy regex, use the following expression

```
expression = ':[%s]+\S'%(hexdigits)
```

This will match only hex words so length of hex+digits is no longer a constraint.